# Android webview runs on Emulator, but not on Galaxy device

Tags: android, web, emulation, galaxy

When I run my app on Android Emulator, it runs beautifully, but not on Samsung Galaxy phone. When I install it on my Galaxy phone, it is successfully installed but it says "Web page not available". Anyone know about that? My Galaxy is GINGERBREAD

Comment: Are you sure you can connect to http://myUrl?

Comment: I think it may be much more benign... are you sure your phone has internet access? Does the URL load in your default browser on the device?

Comment: To Jonas:) No, I can't. Do you figure out my problem? Plz let me know. I'm Johny-comes-lately.

Comment: There is a `SuppressLint` annotation for the `new API` lint. Are you sure that the API level on your phone is high enought to support the line that caused the `newApi` lint?

Comment: Ah, new API? Do you think API will cause a problem, Gumbo? And so, Should I exchange my phone for better one? Otherwise, I don't have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Android Manifest file for: android.permission.INTERNET
You might not have given your app internet permissions.

Comment: Thanks for mention. I have given my app internet permission without doubt. I have checked it out.

Comment: Thanks for awakening me. I thought I had given my app internet permission. At 2nd glance, to my surprise, I haven't. Thanks again. I blame my stupidity.